# make RPM recognize dependency built from source

Tags: yum, rpm

I am trying to emulate an enviroment that has centos5 and tomcat6 (for some reason), which is a problem because there are no RPMs for tomcat6 which are compatible with centos5 available to me.  I do have the source for tomcat6 and I can build it from source.

However, I have a number of RPMs which I would like to use that are dependent on tomcat6.  I know they will run on centos5 and should work if installed.  However, they won't install because even if I did install tomcat6 the RPMs would think it was not installed due to tomcat6 RPM not being installed, only the code.

Is there a way to express to RPM/yum that I have built the program as source and it should move on and do the install anyways?  I know I can just force the install, but is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: no, its easiest to simply force the install assuming you generated an RPM package for the tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have unsatisfied dependencies that you need to stub out.

Make a dummy package that supplies the missing Provides: is
the general approach.

(aside)
RPM5 (this isn't you) also permits Requires: to be stubbed out
using a configuration file /etc/rpm/sysinfo/Providename.